# A difference of 10 days in Access SQL

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, datediff, date-difference

I want to show how many orders have been shipped 10 days before the required date in Access SQL, but I can't seem to get the syntax right.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Orders
WHERE DATEDIFF(day,RequiredDate,ShippedDate)=10;
```

Comment: Which error message you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM Orders
WHERE (((DateDiff("d",[Orders].[RequiredDate],[Orders].[ShippedDate]))=10));
```